# Need the Entire List of UAC Protected Resources to Run My Application as a Standard User (unelevated)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb6, uac

In relation to upgrading my VB6 app to run as a Standard User as opposed to always requiring Elevated Privileges, I'm finding it hard to figure out all the bits of the VB6 legacy application (exe) that I need to change.

At the moment, my understanding of what a "Protected Resource" as far as UAC is concerned are as follows:

In the Registry, you can't access HK_LocalMachine (Local Machine) and must user HK_CurrentUser instead, because the HK LocalMachine needs elevated privileges and the CurrentUser doesn't.

In the Files & Folders section, I know I can't access the Windows directory (C:\Windows) or any of its subfolders, because that, including the Program Files Directory (C:\Program Files) is a Protected Resource & requires elevation, so instead we are to use the ProgramData folder which doesn't require elevation instead.

Also, I think some programs require elevation if you want to run them, such as the Event Viewer? Is there a list of all programs that require elevation to run somewhere? What about programs that run inside cmd.exe console?

Now, I'm not even sure if my use of the term "Protected Resource" is correct, because when I did several different types of google searches, I could not find the other Protected Resources that I do not know about. Basically, I need to know what all the other "Protected Resources" are so that I know which parts of my VB6 application need changing in order for me to run my app on users machines responsibly (without requiring elevation).

Because I was unable to find the List of all Protected Resources Restricted by UAC in Vista and above, I do not know which parts of my VB6 EXE need changing. This is basically my problem. At the moment, the only things I know I need to change are the items listed above: In the Registry, using CurrentUser instead of LocalMachine, and in the FileSystem, using ProgramData instead of %WinDir% and %ProgramFiles%. What are all the blacklisted Directories?

Basically, doing a search for the List of all the Protected Resources returned nothing on Google, can someone please direct me to some site where I can get a comprehensive list of all the items that need elevation in order to work? So that this way, I can use alternative method when re-coding my VB6 EXE so people can run my app without giving it Administrative Privileges?

Also, any differences in these "Protected Resources" between Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8/8.1 as necessary or as you see fit, the more I know the better.

Also, it's impossible for me to re-test every single part of the application in order to see if it stops working or not, as the app has too many different parts and is 20,000 lines of code long. I need a document which outlines this properly so I can go in there and change what needs to be changed instead of trying to do trial & error.

Thank you so much!

***Update/Edit/Summary:***

Here are items that I would find useful. I know of four (4) categories that contain Protected Resources, they are: The Registry, FileSystem Folders, Applications installed with Windows and Windows API's.

1). If there is another category or categories that may contain protected resources, please feel free to list them.
2). A List of Registry Keys that are Protected Registry Objects & require elevation to access.
3). A List of Folders that are Protected Folders & require elevation to access.
4). A List of Windows Applications that are Protected Applications and require elevation to run.
5). A List of Windows API's that are Protected API's and require elevation to use.

Comment: UAC is simple: if you aren't elevated, you don't have administrator privilege - exactly as if the program was running in a standard user account.  If your program doesn't run under UAC in Vista, then it didn't run for a standard user in XP.

Comment: Access to files and the registry is controlled by ACLs; if you're not sure whether you can access a particular directory or registry key, you can check the ACL.  Some APIs require admin access as well, in almost all cases the MSDN documentation for the API is explicit about this - but it's usually easy to guess, if the API does something that only an administrator should be allowed to do, then it probably requires admin access; otherwise it probably doesn't.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Not sure I understand you, but all I need is a list of things I can't do (documented) in a standard account. Once I have this list, I'll be able to know which parts of my legacy VB6 application I need to change in order to make sure I am not doing those things. This way, I will be able to run my legacy app as a Standard User without any errors or exceptions being thrown. Get me? I need the documented list of items, some of those items I outlined in my post, I just need to know the rest.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Ok, so Registry & FileSystem + some API's. 1). Where do I get a list of those API's that I cannot use as a Standard User, and 2). Apart from the Registry, FileSystem, API's & some App's, what else is there? 3). Is there a list of those windows applications that can't run as Standard User published somewhere?

Basically, need list of RegKeys, Folders, Windows App's, Windows API's that I cannot run as Standard User. In addition, anything else apart from those 4 categories that I have not been able to imagine.

Comment: Welcome to the 21st century.

Comment: Well, MSDN has a list of all APIs, and the documentation for each API says if/when it needs admin privilege.  That's probably the best there is, so far as official documentation goes.  I can't imagine anybody else has compiled a big list of "all APIs that use admin privilege" but, well, who knows what's on the internet?  As for Windows applications, you can tell by looking for the UAC shield on the application icons.

Comment: @Deanna Thank you for your welcome, but I've been using .NET since 2001, this is just an old program that I will never have time to upgrade to .NET and I want to make it usable without requiring Admin Rights. Of course, if I had decided to turn my users UAC off or insisted on running it elevated permanently, then I would have gotten criticized for not removing the unnecessary elevation dependency.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Ok, I suppose I can do specific searches for FileSystem objects and HK Registry Objects. However, apart from those 4 categories, is there anything else I am missing or haven't thought of categorically speaking?

Comment: Probably, though nothing springs immediately to mind.  There's no getting around the need for testing, I'm afraid.

Comment: My point was that the rules on what you can access haven't changed since at the latest, Windows 2000, and before that in the NT branch. UAC just enforces the guidelines that have been in place since last century (before you started using .Net :p)

Comment: @HarryJohnston I of course will test, but I need to know what to change before I test the things that I've changed. Testing to try to find UAC violations is counter-productive, I am hoping to know what resources are protected, then I want to change my app where needed, then test. Thank for your help, of course, if anyone can think of any protected categories outside the 4 we've isolated, please feel free to provide an answer. Also, if you have lists for any of the categories, please feel free to answer, I am happily accepting answers until we can compile lists and I can share it with everyone.

Comment: @Deanna Thanks for your clarification, I understand what you're saying, that it hasn't changed. However, my problem is that I'm not sure I know or knew what the items were to begin with. Additionally, I'm not confident that I know or knew all the items from back in the NT days or even from the present day.

I don't know the things that I don't know about. So hopefully we might get someone who can point us towards some categories, lists or documentation that clarifies for me if I have covered everything or if I have missed anything. Thank you again.

Comment: Also, to the two people that close-voted this post, please do not do that. I understand that you may not find this post useful, just because you do not find this post useful, it doesn't mean that I don't. I obviously have a very real use or need for it, which is why I've invested the time to ask this question. I've spent the last few days on this UAC stuff, yet again. Lets not be petty to one another, we are all adults and can do better than that. I also noticed you both have up voted each others negative comments towards me... that's tactless! @Deanna

Comment: My close vote was due to it being too broad. The subject of "Everything that I'm not allowed to do" is by its very nature, too broad. What you are allowed to access without elevating is a much smaller list and consists of "The user's profile".

Comment: Well essentially there's a quite simple question, which determines if you need elevated priviledges: "Does this action change anything, which is not limited to the current user?"  
If the answer is yes, you will most likely see an UAC promt and vice versa.

Comment: To assist such migration, Microsoft has ACT published a long time ago (Windows Vista time frame), so it is really strange that you ask such questions now, instead of reading previous discussions. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7352 I voted to close this question based on this.

Comment: The problem is that there are guidelines on what to do? If you follow them then no problem. But you are asking the reverse of that question. What am I not allowed to do? See the `Application Specification for Microsoft Windows 2000 for Desktop Applications` which predates UAC but if you follow it everything will work. The rules are far older than UAC. UAC merely enforces the rules.

Answer (score 2):

When your application is running in a normal LUA environment, you normally only have full access to that user's profile.
This includes:

1. Their profile folder: `C:\Users\[username]\`
2. Their registry hive: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`

By extension, any setting or change that applies just to that user can be made without elevating.

Anything outside this is either no access or just read only, including (but not limited to):

1. Global settings
2. The system registry hives: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`
3. System folders: `C:\Windows\`, `C:\Program Files\`, `C:\ProgramData\` (unless explicitly allowed)
4. Other user's profiles
5. Raw hardware access
6. Next door's dog
7. Nuclear missile launch codes

Further reading:

1. [Windows Vista Application Development Requirements for User Account Control (UAC)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905330.aspx)
2. [Windows Vista Application Development Requirements for User Account Control Compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb530410.aspx) (A longer article)

Comment: You also have access to any other drives on the system, at least as far as ACLs allow it.  Application folders created under the ProgramData folder inherit "owner" security by default, which means standard users can control items they've created there while others can only read them.  More typically an installer creates such folders and sets custom access rights on them.